# How can i use informations after create textBox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, button, textbox, openfiledialog

I created function for manually add textBox and Button.

**Here is my actually scripts:**

```
    private void OpenFileDialogButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string souborFilename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            filePathText.Text = souborFilename;
        }
    }

    private void nextDialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (calculate <= 7)
        {
            TextBox text = new TextBox();
            text.Location = new Point(filePathText.Location.X, filePathText.Location.Y + y);
            text.Size = new Size(194, 20);
            text.ReadOnly = true;
            text.Name = "filePathText" + "{calculate}";
            //MessageBox.Show(text.Name);
            this.Controls.Add(text);

            Button button = new Button();
            button.Location = new Point(OpenFileDialogButton.Location.X, OpenFileDialogButton.Location.Y + y);
            button.Size = new Size(33, 24);
            button.Text = "...";
            button.Click += new EventHandler(OpenFileDialogButton_Click);
            this.Controls.Add(button);

            this.nextDialog.Location = new Point(22, 49 + y);
        }
        else
        {
            this.nextDialog.Controls.Remove(nextDialog);
            this.nextDialog.Dispose();
            MessageBox.Show("Maximální možnost počtů přidaných souborů byla dosažena!");
        }

        y = y + 28;
        calculate++;
    }
```

When user click on nextDialog button so its created correct next button and textboxt but all buttons have same functions. Each button have own textBox.

Problem is that every button still change same textBox after used openFileDialog. And i need that each button change only his own textBox.

So i need help with function **"OpenFileDialogButton_Click"**.

**Exactly this part:**

**filePathText.Text** = This is my default TextBox name than i started use function for manually add textbox and button. It is necessary to make it dynamic.

```
filePathText.Text = souborFilename;
```

Here is picture with my problems:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SETFE.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gENf.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button has a [`Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Property that can take an Object, try putting your associated TextBox's name in it, then use the [`Controls.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method to locate the TextBox that has that name. Something like this.

Your Modified NextDialog Method:

```
private void nextDialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (calculate <= 7)
    {
        TextBox text = new TextBox();
        text.Location = new Point(filePathText.Location.X, filePathText.Location.Y + y);
        text.Size = new Size(194, 20);
        text.ReadOnly = true;
        text.Name = "filePathText" + "{calculate}";
        //MessageBox.Show(text.Name);
        this.Controls.Add(text);

        Button button = new Button();
        button.Location = new Point(OpenFileDialogButton.Location.X, OpenFileDialogButton.Location.Y + y);
        button.Size = new Size(33, 24);
        button.Text = "...";
        button.Tag = text.Name;  //Name of associated TextBox added to Tag Property
        button.Click += new EventHandler(OpenFileDialogButton_Click);
        this.Controls.Add(button);

        this.nextDialog.Location = new Point(22, 49 + y);
    }
    else
    {
        this.nextDialog.Controls.Remove(nextDialog);
        this.nextDialog.Dispose();
        MessageBox.Show("Maximální možnost počtů přidaných souborů byla dosažena!");
    }

    y = y + 28;
    calculate++;
}
```

Your Event Handler:

```
private void OpenFileDialogButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Button btn = sender as Button; //Get the Button that was clicked
        string souborFilename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        this.Controls.Find((string)btn.Tag), true )[0].Text = souborFilename; //Find textbox that matches stored name
                                                                             //since method returns an array you will
                                                                             //have to access it threw an index.
    }
}
```

Comment: Your idea still write me this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: did you assign the name of the textbox to your Buttons.Tag Property like I did in your NextDialogClick eventHandler ?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is create custom control with TextBox and Button and add that control on nextDialog Click.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to give name to the new button you are creating and based on the sender name in "OpenFileDialogButton_Click" assign the text box.

```
button.Name = "btn";

 private void OpenFileDialogButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string souborFilename = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            string s = ((Button)sender).Name;

            if (s == "btn")
            {
                Newtextbox.Text = "";
            }
            else
                filePathText.Text = souborFilename;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your function binding like -

```
button.Click += OpenFileDialogButton_Click(text);
```

Your function can be like -

```
private EventHandler OpenFileDialogButton_Click(TextBox txt){ //Your code  }
```

It will facilitate you to pass newly created textbox object every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the event handler for the dynamic *OpenFileDialogButton* button like this:

```
private void nextDialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ...
  TextBox text = new TextBox();
  text.Location = new Point(filePathText.Location.X, filePathText.Location.Y + y);
  text.Size = new Size(194, 20);
  text.ReadOnly = true;
  text.Name = "filePathText" + "{calculate}";
  //MessageBox.Show(text.Name);
  this.Controls.Add(text);

  Button button = new Button();
  button.Location = new Point(OpenFileDialogButton.Location.X, OpenFileDialogButton.Location.Y + y);
  button.Size = new Size(33, 24);
  button.Text = "...";

  // -- start changes
  button.Click += (o, args) => {
    using (var opf = new OpenFileDialog()) {
      if (opf.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
        var souborFilename = opf.FileName;
        text.Text = souborFilename;
      }
    }
  };
  // -- end changes

  this.Controls.Add(button);

  this.nextDialog.Location = new Point(22, 49 + y);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void OpenFileDialogButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string souborFilename = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            foreach (var control in this.Controls)
            {
                if (control is TextBox)
                {
                    TextBox tb = control as TextBox;
                    Button b = sender as Button;
                    if(b != null && tb.Name.Equals("filePathText" + b.Name.Substring(b.Name.Count()-1,1)))
                    {
                        tb.Text = souborFilename;
                    }
                }
            }
            filePathText.Text = souborFilename;
        }
    }

    private void nextDialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (calculate <= 7)
        {
            TextBox text = new TextBox();
            text.Location = new Point(filePathText.Location.X, filePathText.Location.Y + y);
            text.Size = new Size(194, 20);
            text.ReadOnly = true;
            text.Name = "filePathText" + calculate.ToString();
            //MessageBox.Show(text.Name);
            this.Controls.Add(text);

            Button button = new Button();
            button.Location = new Point(OpenFileDialogButton.Location.X, OpenFileDialogButton.Location.Y + y);
            button.Size = new Size(33, 24);
            button.Text = "...";
            button.Click += new EventHandler(OpenFileDialogButton_Click);
            button.Name = "filePathButton" + calculate.ToString();
            this.Controls.Add(button);

            this.nextDialog.Location = new Point(22, 49 + y);
        }
        else
        {
            this.nextDialog.Controls.Remove(nextDialog);
            this.nextDialog.Dispose();
            MessageBox.Show("Maximální možnost počtů přidaných souborů byla dosažena!");
        }

        y = y + 28;
        calculate++;
    }
```